# when i try to upgrade my system from 21.04 to 22.04 it doesnt let me

Tags: upgrade

when I try to upgrade my system from 21.04 to 22.04, it tells me "a problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your internet connection and retry" although I am connected to the internet

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 had one intended *release-upgrade* path; to the next release of Ubuntu 21.10.  When [Ubuntu 21.10 reached EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/) that *supported* upgrade path ceased. You didn't provide specifics on your actual error, but it maybe because 21.04 is EOL (*thus it's repositories were dropped/moved*) but you'd have noted that long ago, refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades & https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/

Comment: do you mean upgrading to 21.10 then 22.04

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu has LTS releases that can *release-upgrade* to the next LTS release; or you can use non-LTS releases that are released during the two year development cycle for the LTS. Ubuntu 22.04's development started in April 2020; it's non-LTS releases were 20.10, 21.04 & 21.10 before finally reaching the LTS release of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  You were using an *interim* release from the middle of the cycle which *release-upgraded* to the next release in that cycle.

Comment: so can i not upgrade now or what?

Comment: You could have *release-upgraded* to 21.10 anytime after it was released; however that path ended when 21.10 reached EOL (see the link in my first comment; the release tool reads https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release so won't upgrade to a release that has "*Supported: 0*" listed against it.

Comment: If you're using a desktop release; you can *upgrade via re-install* which does not impact any user files, and will have your *manually installed* packages auto-reinstall (*if available in Ubuntu [official] repositories and internet is available during install so as to download them*), but it's not intended for server systems.  Read your messages; have you applied the EOLUpgrade required instructions, once done you can try *do-release-upgrade* again...  If you've done that; backup & re-install maybe your only choice, but remember 21.04 = 2021-April, add 9 months or 2022-January is when upgrade

Comment: thanks to everyone I just finished the update